# How to fix 1004 error with macros in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

We have the main file on our server which contains all the VBA code and macros. We have local files in a bunch of machines in the company on which the macros from the main file are being called to start a procedure. Not sure why but recently they stopped working properly. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

I checked the macros settings and they are enabled on all computers so this is not the case. It was working fine last week but it all started in this week.

```
Private Sub CommandButton_CreatePanelTest_Click()
    Application.Run ("'Y:\XXX\Main.xlsm'!CreatePanelMacro")
    IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended = False
    Workbooks(Dir("Y:\XXX\Main.xlsm")).Close Savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the workbook before you run a macro in it.

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = Workbooks.Open("Y:\XXX\Main.xlsm")
Application.Run "'Main.xlsm'!CreatePanelMacro"
IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended = False
Wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```